# Can't crop image's size in Blender 2.8

Tags: edit-mode, compositing-nodes, image, pixel-art

Hi I want to make pixel art from my 3D renders and I found that scaling render result in compositor and pixelating it with node gives better result than rendering with low resolution.

Problem is that I can't crop it in blender and it's still big image with small pixelart in center 
[image]

So I want to get rid of this transparent area. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an **Output**->**File Output** Node
[image: Composite nodes]

When you render the image a full render will happen, then the **Compositor** will crop it

[image: rendered and cropped in compositor]

But at the same time a file will be saved that is just the result of the crop.

[image: file output]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much :)